# sudo composer install vs. composer install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I run `sudo composer install` I got this warning

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

I tried just `composer install` I got this error

> **[ErrorException]**
>     file_put_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/vendor/composer/installed.json): faile
>     d to open stream: Permission denied

Here is the current permission set on my Laravel folder

```
total 1872
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     777 Feb 27 20:18 phpunit.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff      87 Feb 27 20:18 phpspec.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     481 Feb 27 20:18 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   3 bheng  staff     102 Feb 27 20:18 note
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     967 Feb 27 20:18 md-bheng-readme.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     503 Feb 27 20:18 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff      26 Feb 27 20:18 contributors.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff    1635 Feb 27 20:18 artisan
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff      43 Feb 27 20:18 Procfile
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff    5634 Feb 27 20:18 Gruntfile.js
drwxr-xr-x   4 bheng  staff     136 Feb 27 20:18 tests
drwxr-xr-x   5 bheng  staff     170 Feb 27 20:18 storage
drwxr-xr-x   4 bheng  staff     136 Feb 27 20:18 sql
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     560 Feb 27 20:18 server.php
drwxr-xr-x   5 bheng  staff     170 Feb 27 20:18 resources
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff     105 Feb 27 20:18 pull.sh
drwxr-xr-x   7 bheng  staff     238 Mar  1 14:46 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--@  1 bheng  staff       0 Mar  1 14:46 Icon?
drwxr-xr-x  22 bheng  staff     748 Mar  2 11:47 app
drwxrwxrwx@ 27 bheng  staff     918 Mar  3 14:55 public
drwxr-xr-x   8 bheng  staff     272 Mar  6 13:25 database
-rw-------@  1 bheng  staff     405 Mar 14 09:29 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------   1 bheng  staff    1766 Mar 14 09:29 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff  126713 Mar 14 10:00 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  18 bheng  staff     612 Mar 28 21:24 config
-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff    1022 Mar 30 12:21 composer.json
drwxr-xr-x  32 bheng  staff    1088 Mar 30 12:21 vendor
```

---

Here is what inside my composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravelcollective/remote": "5.1.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.3",
    "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [ "database" ],

            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            }
            },
            "autoload-dev": {
                "classmap": [
                "tests/TestCase.php"
                ]
                },
                "scripts": {
                    "post-install-cmd": [
                    "php artisan clear-compiled",
                    "php artisan optimize"
                    ],
                    "post-update-cmd": [
                    "php artisan clear-compiled",
                    "php artisan optimize"
                    ],
                    "post-create-project-cmd": [
                    "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
                    "php artisan key:generate"
                    ]
                    },
                    "config": {
                        "preferred-install": "dist"
                    }
                }
```

**How do I fix this ? Do I need to chmod any folders ?**

Comment: Delete your vendor directory and run `composer install` again.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I'm on it.

Comment: personally I do `sudo --user=www-data composer install` to run as the apache user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Delete your vendor directory and run `composer install` again.

You're getting the permission denied error because the `vendor/composer/installed.json` file was created by the root user when you ran `sudo composer install`, so now when you run `composer install` your user doesn't have permission to edit that file.

**Update:**

If you are working within a live document root (you shouldn't be - read up on [atomic deployment](https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/atomic-deployments-from-scratch/)) then you can try `chown` on the vendor directory and its contents to avoid any downtime between the deletion and re-running `composer install`:

```
$ sudo chown -R myuser: vendor/
```

Replace `myuser` with your username.

Comment: and what is the solution for this?

Comment: @Aziz the solution is the first sentence of this answer. Always run composer install _without_ sudo

Comment: I mean if i already started once with sudo. how can i solve it without removing everything from the server?

Comment: @Aziz you shouldn’t be making changes like this to a live document root. Take a look into atomic deployment